# Creating Webservices from EJB 3.0 JBoss developer studio with EAP 6.2

Tags: web-services, jboss, ejb-3.0, jbossws

Getting issue when generating client - A class/interface with the same name "exercise.order.bean.GetAccountResp
onse" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 22 of /exWeb/BusinessBean?wsdl

Here is wsdl -

```
    <wsdl:definitions name="BusinessBeanService" targetNamespace="http://bean.order.exercise/"><wsdl:types><xs:schema targetNamespace="http://bean.order.exercise/" version="1.0"><xs:element name="GetAccount" type="tns:GetAccount"/><xs:element name="GetAccountResponse" type="tns:GetAccountResponse"/><xs:complexType name="GetAccount"><xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="getAccountRequest" type="tns:getAccountRequest"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType><xs:complexType name="getAccountRequest"><xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="accountID" type="xs:string"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="clientID" type="xs:string"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType><xs:complexType name="GetAccountResponse"><xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:getAccountResponse"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType><xs:complexType name="getAccountResponse"><xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="accountID" type="xs:string"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="accountName" type="xs:string"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="clientID" type="xs:string"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="orderCount" type="xs:string"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="GetAccountResponse"><wsdl:part element="tns:GetAccountResponse" name="parameters">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="GetAccount"><wsdl:part element="tns:GetAccount" name="parameters">
</wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:portType name="BusinessBean"><wsdl:operation name="GetAccount"><wsdl:input message="tns:GetAccount" name="GetAccount">
</wsdl:input><wsdl:output message="tns:GetAccountResponse" name="GetAccountResponse">
</wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:binding name="BusinessBeanServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:BusinessBean"><soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><wsdl:operation name="GetAccount"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/><wsdl:input name="GetAccount"><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output name="GetAccountResponse"><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding><wsdl:service name="BusinessBeanService"><wsdl:port binding="tns:BusinessBeanServiceSoapBinding" name="BusinessBeanPort"><soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/exWeb/BusinessBean"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

EJB -

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class BusinessBean implements BusinessService {

@EJB private DataServiceLocal dataService;

   @Override
   @WebMethod
   @WebResult
   public GetAccountResponse GetAccount(@WebParam GetAccountRequest getAccountRequest) {

    GetAccountResponse gResponse = new GetAccountResponse();

    String clientID =  getAccountRequest.getAccountID();
    String accountID = getAccountRequest.getAccountID();

    //Find the list of order
    Order order = dataService.findOrder(accountID);

    //Find the account details
    Account account = dataService.findAccount(accountID);

    gResponse.setAccountID(accountID);
    gResponse.setAccountName(account.getAccname());
    gResponse.setClientID(clientID);
    gResponse.setOrderCount("");

    return gResponse;       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is likely going to be the web service parameter style you're using. JAX-WS defaults to the [`WRAPPED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jws/soap/SOAPBinding.html#parameterStyle%28%29) parameter style.

What this means is that in the WSDL, there will already be a `GetAccountResponse` type, that represents the response message that your webservice generates. This type (or part) is different and separate from the `GetAccountResponse` class that you have declared as the output of your webservice operation. This result of this duplication is what you're experiencing.

To resolve, use the `autoNameResolution` parameter when importing the WSDL.

```
   wsimport BusinessBean.wsdl -B-XautoNameResolution
```

See also:

- [Naming conflict JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-228)